# Is there Standard literature on compilation of event networks?

Tags: event-driven

Given an arbitrary DAG-based event-network, think FRP-networks, it should be possible to create an "optimal" imperative representation that it could be compiled to. This probably involves topological sorting and graph reduction algorithms.

Is there some standard literature that could be recommended on this topic? My Google-fu fails me at this point.

Comment: This topic seems like it would be more appropriate for CS http://cs.stackexchange.com/ To ask it, you need a good idea of what "optimal" would mean. If you try to solve the problem in general, considering what happens inside each node, it will be reduced to the halting problem. Without considering what happens inside each node you won't be able to eliminate unnecessary computations from nodes built by something that disregards an input like `\x y -> y`.

Comment: @Cirdec: funfact ... I didn't meant to put the `haskell` tag there ... I just now noticed it after seeing your name that I was familiar with from haskell questions.

Comment: @Cirdec I am searching for a way to accelerate (Haskell) FRP networks. Most nodes will contain pure functions and I can disregard users creating looping code in nodes.